# How to transform Dask.DataFrame to pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

How can I transform my resulting dask.DataFrame into pandas.DataFrame (let's say I am done with heavy lifting, and just want to apply sklearn to my aggregate result)?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can call the .compute() method to transform a dask.dataframe to a pandas dataframe:

```
df = df.compute()
```

Comment: Would it be possible to rename it to something more intuitive, e.g. `to_pandas()`?

Comment: Probably not, no.  `.compute()` is pretty standard among all dask collections.

Comment: `.to_compute()` is actually quite intuitive to anyone working with dask.

Comment: @MRocklin, I am reading all the csv's from a folder and I cannot explicitly mention each column names and its dtypes. and merging all df's to single df on a common column. when I m doing df.compute, I get `ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata`, how to handle this

Comment: @pyd, check the `meta` in `read_csv`, which can be provided by a normal `pandas.read_csv()`; but you need to make sure such `meta` info is consistent across all the files you are reading in.

Answer (score 5):

MRocklin's answer is correct and this answer gives more details on when it's appropriate to convert from a Dask DataFrame to and Pandas DataFrame (and how to predict when it'll cause problems).

Each partition in a Dask DataFrame is a Pandas DataFrame.  Running `df.compute()` will coalesce all the underlying partitions in the Dask DataFrame into a single Pandas DataFrame.  That'll cause problems if the size of the Pandas DataFrame is bigger than the RAM on your machine.

If `df` has 30 GB of data and your computer has 16 GB of RAM, then `df.compute()` will blow up with a memory error.  If `df` only has 1 GB of data, then you'll be fine.

You can run `df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()` to compute the amount of memory that your DataFrame is using.  This'll let you know if your DataFrame is sufficiently small to be coalesced into a single Pandas DataFrame.

Repartioning changes the number of underlying partitions in a Dask DataFrame.  `df.repartition(1).partitions[0]` is conceptually similar to `df.compute()`.

Converting to a Pandas DataFrame is especially possible after performing a big filtering operation.  If you filter a 100 billion row dataset down to 10 thousand rows, then you can probably just switch to the Pandas API.

Answer (score -3):

```
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(dsk_df)
```

Here you go. It's faster than `dsk_df.compute()`.

Comment: In my experience this just returns a dataframe with only the columns names transposed in a single row.